# How to create a magnetic vertical scroll using angular and angular-scroll?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular structure for a site that has a series of pages with sections. Each sections of those pages inherits responsively the width and height of the window frame so that as you scroll vertically they become full spreads.

I would like to recreate the effect found from this site "http://andrewgooch.com/" in terms of the vertical magnetic scroll part. Which keeps the frame in position until a certain threshold has been passed. And am not interested in the representation of the frame position on the right as angular-scroll handles this already pretty nicely.

Therefore could anyone help me figure out how to write that part out for angular?

Here is my code so far:

```
 $scope.goToSection = function( section ) {
        console.log(' section loaded with section: ', section );
        clearTimeout( $scope.timeout );

        $scope.humanScrolling = false;

        var top = 0;
        var duration = 2000; //milliseconds

        var someElement = angular.element( document.getElementById( section ) );

        $document.scrollToElement( someElement, top, duration);
      };

      $scope.delay = 100; // delay before last scroll action
      $scope.timeout = null;

      $document.on('scroll', function() {
        // console.log('Document scrolled to ', $document.scrollLeft(), $document.scrollTop());

        var topPosition = $document.scrollTop();

        if ( !$scope.directionTracker ) {
          console.log('directionTracker was empty');
          $scope.directionTracker = topPosition;
        } else if ( topPosition === $scope.directionTracker ) {
           // same value so ignore
        } else if ( topPosition > $scope.directionTracker ) {

          if ( topPosition ) {

            console.log('going down');
            $scope.$apply();

            $scope.directionTracker = topPosition;

            if ( $scope.scrolling === false ) {
              // $scope.scrolling = true;
              clearTimeout( $scope.timeout );
              $scope.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                // alert('scrolling stopped');
                console.log("lastscroll down");

                if ( $scope.humanScrolling ) {
                  $scope.goToSection('container-section-' + ( $scope.currentSection + 1) );
                } else {
                  $scope.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    $scope.humanScrolling = true;
                    clearTimeout( $scope.timeout );
                  }, 200 );
                }

              }, $scope.delay );
            }
          }

        } else if ( topPosition < $scope.directionTracker ) {

          if ( topPosition ) {

            console.log('going up');
            $scope.$apply();

            $scope.directionTracker = topPosition;

            if ( $scope.scrolling === false ) {
              // $scope.scrolling = true;
              clearTimeout( $scope.timeout );
              $scope.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                // alert('scrolling stopped');
                console.log("lastscroll up");

                if ( $scope.humanScrolling ) {
                  $scope.goToSection('container-section-' + $scope.currentSection );
                } else {
                  $scope.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    $scope.humanScrolling = true;
                    clearTimeout( $scope.timeout );
                  }, 200 );
                }

              }, $scope.delay );
            }
          }

        }
      });
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Cheers,